# How to create Model classes in Spring Data JPA when more than one tables are having Composite Primary Keys?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 tables which and having multiple Primary Keys. I was trying to join the model/entity classes but getting many issues.

I have gone through Google and applied many thoughts but no luck.

I am looking for support, on how to Join these tables. My requirement is like when I tried to fetch Parents then I need child records as well.

Attached reference, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0ZYS.jpg)

I was not able to Join the tables and looking for support on how to Join 3 tables which are having Composite Primary Keys.

I am using Spring Boot, Spring Data JPA & MS SQLServer. Also looking for, How to do Create & Update operations on the tables using Spring Data JPA?